# Differential expression in Fourier's paper "Theory of Heat"

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

***The Following is from Fourier's paper in which he says:***

It is easy now to generalize this result and to recognize that it exists in every case of the varied movement of heat expressed by the equation $v = F(x, y, z, t)$.

Let us in fact denote by $x', y', z'$, the co-ordinates of this point $m$, and its actual temperature by $v'$ . Let $x'+ξ,y'+η,z'+ζ$, be the co-ordinates of a point $μ$ infinitely near to the point m, and whose temperature is $w$; $ξ, η, ζ$ are quantities infinitely small added to the co-ordinates $x', y', z'$ ; they determine the position of molecules infinitely near to the point $m$, with respect to three rectangular axes, whose origin is at $m$, parallel to the axes of $x, y,$ and $z$.

Differentiating the equation

$v = F(x, y, z, t)$

and replacing the differentials by $ξ, η, ζ$, we shall have, to express the value of $w$ which is equivalent to $v+dv$, the linear equation $w = v'+$$\frac{du'}{dx}ξ+$$\frac{du'}{dy}η+$$\frac{du'}{dz}ζ$;

the coefficients $u'$,$\frac{du'}{dx}$,$\frac{du'}{dy}$,$\frac{du'}{dz}$ are functions of $x, y, z, t$, in which the given and
constant values $x', y', z'$, which belong to the point $m$, have been substituted for $x, y, z$.

***My question has to do with his differentiation. While he has a function with four variables he differentiate it only for the three of them $x,y,z$. It is correct? Why?***

*You can find the paper here: page 80*

https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/fourier1878.pdf

Comment: Is $\nu ' = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$? It looks like he took a total differential (1st order taylor approximation t0 the change in the function), but if so, then $w$ should be something like $d\nu$ and not $\nu + d\nu$

Comment: No, $ν′=∂F/∂t$ is not the case.

Comment: At a given instant in time, he is looking at (with a first order approximation) the temperature at a different spatial location. $F(x,y,z,t)$ is then a function of 3 variables. He's saying he knows the temperature of $m$ to be $v'$. He wants to know the temperature at the point $\mu$, infinitely close to $m$, at the same time (emphasis at the same time). This is what I think is going on. Just because you have a multivariable function $f(x,y,z)$ doesn't mean you have to let at the inputs vary. If I keep $y,z$ fixed then $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$.

Comment: But you are right, his language is not precise, especially if you just glance at the equation on page 80 (maybe in the surrounding text he wrote something that would have made his statement more understandable)